# MATLAB: sum of one row

Tags: matlab, mean

I am trying to streamline my code. I have a 2-column array from which I'd like to extract the averages of the columns and store them as X and Y.

I tried using the following code:

```
[x y] = mean(theArray);
```

...However, this returns

```
??? Error using ==> mean
Too many output arguments.
```

For now, I have settled with the three lines:

```
coords = mean(theArray);
x = coords(1);
y = coords(2);
```

I'm sure there *must* be a much simpler way of doing this in less than three lines. My code is running an eye tracking device at 1000Hz and I want to avoid any unnecessary processing...

Any wisdom gratefully received

Comment: Do you have reason to believe the three-line version has poor performance?  Have you measured it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In two lines:

```
x = mean(theArray(:,1));
y = mean(theArray(:,2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is already pretty darn simple. You can do it in a one-liner, using this or similar in-line array rearranging code.

```
[x,y] = deal(mean(theArray(:,1)), mean(theArray(:,2)));
```

But in efficiency terms your original three liner is probably better. Splitting the array out before the `mean` call will allocate more memory and costs an extra `mean()` call. You could get it down to two lines without the extra memory and `mean()`.

```
tmp = mean(theArray);
[x,y] = deal(tmp(1), tmp(2));
```

But that really just accomplishes the same thing as your original code, paying an additional function call at run time to save a line on paper.

Throw your code in the Matlab profiler with `profile on` and see if you actually have a problem before trying to optimize. I'll bet none of these are distinguishable in practice, in which case you can stick with whatever's most readable.